# How can I deploy smart contract with front-end . Like REMIX IDE is doing

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, remix, decentralized-applications

I just want to know that if there is any method or mechanics to deploy contract with a single click like REMIX IDE is doing. I just want to deploy new contract with different parameters. I don't want to use truffle or REMIX to deploy my contracts I just want my own deploy method.
Please let me know if possible. And I just want to know that how others are deploying contract instance for every new parameter.
**Note** parameters means value in constructor.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```js
myContract.deploy({
    data: '0x12345...',
    arguments: [123, 'My String']
})
.send({
    from: '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891',
    gas: 1500000,
    gasPrice: '30000000000000'
}, function(error, transactionHash){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.on('transactionHash', function(transactionHash){ ... })
.on('receipt', function(receipt){
   console.log(receipt.contractAddress) // contains the new contract address
})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ ... })
.then(function(newContractInstance){
    console.log(newContractInstance.options.address) // instance with the new contract address
});


// When the data is already set as an option to the contract itself
myContract.options.data = '0x12345...';

myContract.deploy({
    arguments: [123, 'My String']
})
.send({
    from: '0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891',
    gas: 1500000,
    gasPrice: '30000000000000'
})
.then(function(newContractInstance){
    console.log(newContractInstance.options.address) // instance with the new contract address
});


// Simply encoding
myContract.deploy({
    data: '0x12345...',
    arguments: [123, 'My String']
})
.encodeABI();
> '0x12345...0000012345678765432'


// Gas estimation
myContract.deploy({
    data: '0x12345...',
    arguments: [123, 'My String']
})
.estimateGas(function(err, gas){
    console.log(gas);
});
```

The following web3 code can be used to deploy a contract on the spot